# How to Deserialize a JSON into a list using SIMPLE JSON?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have the following JSON.

> [{"SaveValues":[{"id":1,"allposition":{"x":-4.888263702392578,"y":4.799035549163818},"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":1},{"id":2,"allposition":{"x":-4.607616424560547,"y":-4.033360004425049},"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":1}],"NoteValues":[{"movenumber":1,"notemsg":"ssd"}]},{"SaveValues":[{"id":1,"allposition":{"x":-4.888263702392578,"y":4.799035549163818},"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":2},{"id":2,"allposition":{"x":-4.607616424560547,"y":-4.033360004425049},"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":2},{"id":2,"allposition":{"x":4.328777313232422,"y":1.9337825775146485},"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":2}],"NoteValues":[{"movenumber":2,"notemsg":"ddf"}]}]

They class used for serialization is given below.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerHandler 
{
    public int id; 
    public Vector2 allposition;
    public Quaternion allrotation;
    public Vector2 allscale;

    public Vector3 linepos0;
    public Vector3 linepos1;
    public int movetype;

    public PlayerHandler(int ids,Vector2 allpos,Quaternion allrot,Vector2 allscal,Vector3 Line0,Vector3 Line1,int Moves)
    {
        this.id = ids;
        this.allposition = allpos;
        this.allrotation = allrot;
        this.allscale = allscal;
        this.linepos0 = Line0;
        this.linepos1 = Line1;
        this.movetype = Moves;
    }

}

[System.Serializable]    
public class PlayerMovement
{
    public int movenumber;
    public string notemsg;

    public PlayerMovement(int Movenum,string Note)
    {
        this.movenumber = Movenum;
        this.notemsg = Note;    
    }
}
```

In the loading method I am trying to deserialize the JSON.So I created a list 
`List<PlayerHandler> SaveValuesDeserialize = new List<PlayerHandler>();`

I am looking to add the SaveValues from the Json.The method I have tried is given below.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + filename, FileMode.Open))
{
    fs.Dispose();
    jsonLoadstring = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, filename));
    JSONNode JNode = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(jsonLoadstring);                

    var deseiralized = JNode[0]["NoteValues"][0]["notemsg"];//Here I am getting the deserialized value for testing.

    //What should I do to get the SaveValues inside the list

    for (int i = 0; i < JNode.Count; i++)
    {
        SaveValuesDeserialize.Add(JNode[i]["SaveValues"][i]);
    }
}
```

I am looking to solve this using SIMPLE JSON.I have tried to use other methods to deserialize which was bit complex to understand.So choose this method to try.Since I am getting the testing values,I hope I can get the values by using SIMPLEJSON.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to deserialize json is often to create classes which model your json object.  You can use [json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com) to create the classes, or use Visual Studio (Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes).

Create the classes below then you can use `JsonConvert` to deserialize the json into your object.  Note that since you're only interested in `SaveValues` you don't need to map other properties (like `NoteValues`).

Code to deserialise into object:

```
var myModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeJson<List<Response>>(json);

// access by iterating through properties
foreach (var item in response)
{
    foreach (var saveValue in item.SaveValues)
    {
        // get all properties of saveValue...
        // saveValue.Allposition;
        // saveValue.Allrotation;
        // saveValue.Allscale;
        // ....
    }
}
```

This deserializes the json to `List<Response>` where `Response` is as below:

```
public class Allposition
{
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
}

public class Allrotation
{
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
    public double z { get; set; }
    public double w { get; set; }
}

public class Allscale
{
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
}

public class Linepos0
{
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
    public double z { get; set; }
}

public class Linepos1
{
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
    public double z { get; set; }
}

public class SaveValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Allposition Allposition { get; set; }
    public Allrotation Allrotation { get; set; }
    public Allscale Allscale { get; set; }
    public Linepos0 Linepos0 { get; set; }
    public Linepos1 Linepos1 { get; set; }
    public int Movetype { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public List<SaveValue> SaveValues { get; set; }
    // NoteValues can safely be removed from model if you don't need the values
    public List<NoteValue> NoteValues { get; set; }
}

// optional
public class NoteValue
{
    public int Movenumber { get; set; }
    public string Notemsg { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer haldo I havent tried your solution but the following I tried and it worked out for me.I have made some changes to class to serialize data so that I can use it deserialize it.

```
public class ListContainer
{

public List<PlayerHandler> SaveValues;
public List<PlayerMovement> NoteValues;


public ListContainer(List<PlayerHandler> _saveVal, List<PlayerMovement> _noteVal)
{
    SaveValues = _saveVal;
    NoteValues = _noteVal;

}

}


[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerHandler 
{
public int id; 
public Vector2 allposition;
public Quaternion allrotation;
public Vector2 allscale;

public Vector3 linepos0;
public Vector3 linepos1;
public int movetype;


public PlayerHandler(int ids,Vector2 allpos,Quaternion allrot,Vector2 allscal,Vector3 Line0,Vector3 Line1,int Moves)

{
    this.id = ids;
    this.allposition = allpos;
    this.allrotation = allrot;
    this.allscale = allscal;
    this.linepos0 = Line0;
    this.linepos1 = Line1;
    this.movetype = Moves;
}


}

[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerMovement
{
public int movenumber;
public string notemsg;

public PlayerMovement(int Movenum,string Note)
{
    this.movenumber = Movenum;
    this.notemsg = Note;

}

}


//Added to retrieve data
[System.Serializable]
public class RootObject
{
    public PlayerHandler[] SaveValues;
    public PlayerMovement[] NoteValues;

    }

//Added to retrieve data
[System.Serializable]
public class RootObjects
{


 public RootObject[] Roots;
}
```

I made a few changes on how to retrieve data.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + filename, FileMode.Open))
{


fs.Dispose();


jsonLoadstring = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, filename));


string saveString = "{ \"Roots\" : " + jsonLoadstring + "}";

GetItems = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootObjects>(saveString);
//Loop GetItems to retrieve data.

}
```